# What's the facebox 'hooks'

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

```
/*
* 
*  Facebox also has a bunch of other hooks:
*
*    loading.facebox
*    beforeReveal.facebox
*    reveal.facebox (aliased as 'afterReveal.facebox')
*    init.facebox
*    afterClose.facebox
*
*/
```

I'm using [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/). In source codes I found some hooks, but I can only find one line that use "beforeReveal":`$(document).trigger('beforeReveal.facebox')`. I can't find where it is defined. So I wonder how it works. Hope to get some help. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are simply custom events (while e.g. `click` is a pre-defined event) that you can subscribe to:

```
$(document).on('beforeReveal.facebox', function() {
    // This code here is now executed every time before the facebox is revealed,
    // because Facebox triggers this event.
});
```

Read more in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: It means I should define them, or they will do nothing?

Comment: Exactly! They are just hooks that allow you to add some action at specific points (before revealing, after revealing etc.).

Answer (score 1):

To clarify these triggers are not actually calling functions defined in the facebox.js sourcecode.  They are just triggers that fire events whether something is there to handle it or not.  However, if you define these functions in your javascript, they will be called when the facebox event happens.

For example if you want to respond to the afterReveal.facebox (or beforeReveal) just add the following line in your javascript ready function which should be in your document head section.

```
$(document).ready (function() {
     //initialize facebox
     $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox(); 

     //create a response to the 'close.facebox' event
     $(document).bind('close.facebox', function() {
          //some function on close if you desire          
     });

     //Create a response to the the 'afterReveal.facebox' event
     $(document).bind('afterReveal.facebox', function() { 
            //Add your functionality here
            $('textarea').autogrow();
            return true;
      });
});
```